# how to change the text box,select box and check box value after the button click event?

Tags: php, html, url, submit-button

```
<html>
<body>
    <form method="post">
     Name :<input type = "text" name= "name" value = "<?php echo $_GET["name"];?>">
     salary :<input type = "number" name = "salary" value = "<?php echo $_GET["salary"]?>">
     <input type = "submit" value = "submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above code, name and salary text box fetches the value from url. And once we change name or salary text box value, and if we submit the form the "post" method will be called and the name salary values will be stored in the table.

 Now my query is once the form is submitted, I want new values of name and salary to be displayed in respective text boxes,and in similar way how can I achieve that in select box, radio box and check boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways:

1. change the method to `get`: `<form method="get">`
2. change the values you echo to:

   `<?php echo isset($_POST["name"])?$_POST["name"]:$_GET["name"];?>`

For select:

```
<select name = "department">
    <?php $output = $connection->get_department(); 
    if($output["status"] == 1){ 
        $array = $output["array"]; 
        foreach($array as $res){?> 
            <option value = "<?php echo $res["id"];?>">
            <?php echo $res["name"]; 
           if(isset($_POST["name"]) && $_POST["name"] == $res["name"]){
               echo " selected"; 
           }?>
            </option>
        <?php
        } 
    } 
    ?> 
</select>
```

Comment: What should i do if i come across same situation for check box ,select box and radio button

Comment: you just check if the value in corresponding post or get is equal to the value in option and if so, you add sttribute 'selected', 'checked' etc, and if not, you omit that.

Comment: I would like, but you didn't provide any checkboxes or selects in your code.

Comment: <select name = "department">                                                                
<?php
 $output = $connection->get_department();
 if($output["status"] == 1){
            $array = $output["array"];
            foreach($array as $res){?>
             <option value = "<?php echo $res["id"];?>"><?php echo $res["name"];?></option><?php
            }
           }
          ?>
         </select>

Answer (score 1):

Change your form method from POST to GET, this will store the variables in the querystring and make them accessible to your `$_GET` variable.

Comment: it doesn't work. By the way before clicking the submit button the name and salary button would display the information fetching from the url. and then if we change name and salary value and then click submit button then it need to display the new record. How do i do tht?

Comment: <td><input type = "text" name = "addition_name" value = "<?php echo isset($_POST["addition_name"])?$_POST["addition_name"]:$_GET["name"];?>" required></td>